# Finding the kernel from $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ to $\mathbb{F}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Exercise.** For $T: \mathbb{F}_3[x] \to \mathbb{F}^2$, find a basis for $\ker(T)$ where

$$T(f) = \begin{bmatrix} f(a) \\ f(b) \end{bmatrix} \hspace{1cm} a \neq b.$$

> $\mathbb{F}^2$ is the space of all 2-dimensional column vectors with entries from some field $\mathbb{F}$.

> $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is the space of all polynomials with degree at most $3$.

This one is tripping me up because of the differing vector spaces, i.e. $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ consisting of polynomials and $\mathbb{F}^2$ consisting of column vectors. I'll show my attempt so far

*Solution*.

Now, $\ker(T) = \Big\{ f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_3[x] \Big| \begin{bmatrix} f(a) \\ f(b) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Big\}$

By design, we have that $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = 0$. Then, it must be true that $f(a) = f(b)$.

Since objects in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ are polynomials, we have that

$x-a \mid f(x)$ and $x-b \mid f(x)$

Then, it must be true that

$$f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)g(x)$$

for some polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{F}_1[x]$ (since $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is limited to degree 3 polynomials).

Let $g(x) = x - k $ for some $k \in \mathbb{F}$. Then, we have

$$f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-k)$$

---

Any ideas on where I should go from here? I know I'm on the right track, but showing kernels of linear transformations that aren't column vectors becomes tricky for me.

Comment: You have a linear transformation from a vector space of dimension $4$ onto a vector space of dimension $2$.  How many dimensions will the kernel of this transformation have?  How large a linearly independent set of polynomials within the kernel do you need to find?  Can you find a large enough set by inspection?  Hint:  $\{1, x, x^2, x^3 \}$ is a basis for $\Bbb F_3[x]$.

Comment: Just checking, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary fixed nonequal constants?

Comment: @Alan That is correct. $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ (fixed) with $a \neq b$. The primary reason for $ a \neq b$ is so that one does not pick $a=b=0$ (assuming that your constant term is also zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\dim\ker(T)=2$.

As you noticed $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-k)$, so $f(x) = x(x-a)(x-b)-k(x-a)(x-b)$.
This shows us that
$\{x(x-a)(x-b), (x-a)(x-b)\}$ is a system of generators for $\ker(T)$, and a basis as well.